# queryset use 'values' for join ,,... template variables is too long name.. can i change it?

Tags: django, inner-join

queryset use values and LEFT join auth_user 
the template variable name is too long

Can I change the template name to a shorter one?

```
queryset = Post.objects.values('id','subject','created_by_id','created_by__first_name')
```

I have to use template variable name like this "post.created_by__first_name" 
It's too long...  can i change it?

Comment: I do not really follow. Why is it too long?

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotate to make an alias, like:

```
from django.db.models import F

queryset = Post.objects.annotate(
    fn=F('created_by__first_name')
).values('id','subject', 'created_by_id', 'fn')
```

But using `.values(..)` is typically *not* a good idea. You can use [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch related objects in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can rename it b using annotate and F object.

```py
from django.db import models

Post.objects.annotate(new=models.F('created_by__first_name')).values('id', 'subject', 'created_by_id', ’new’)
```